# Possible/howto resize iframe on mouse focus?

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize, mouseover

I have two iframes next to each other at 50% width and am wondering if it's possible to resize one iframe to 80% when that iframe is moused over. Is it possible? If so, can someone post a small how-to on getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this in Firefox:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>iframes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="container">
        <iframe id="ifr1" style="width:45%;margin:0">a</iframe>
        <iframe id="ifr2" style="width:45%;margin:0">b</iframe>
      </div>
      <script>
        var dv = document.getElementById('container'),
            ifr1 = document.getElementById('ifr1'), 
            ifr2 = document.getElementById('ifr2');
            swapWidth = function(id){
                if(id === 'ifr1'){
                    ifr2.style.width = '15%';
                    ifr1.style.width = '75%';
                }else{
                    ifr1.style.width = '15%';
                    ifr2.style.width = '75%';
                }
            };
        dv.onmouseover = function(ev){
            ev = ev || window.event;
            var elm = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
            swapWidth(elm.id);
        };
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: add code for IE

Comment: I wasn't able to resize any of the frame on mouseover in internet explorer. Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited the code. Try it, I don't have a windows box around.